# Change dnsmasq's cache

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I would like to alter my dnsmasq's cache so when I look for certain domains it'll give me the IP address I want it to serve (not necessarily the actual IP of that domain). It's basically like poisoning my own DNS server but not remotely.

Where is dnsmasq's cache saved? How can I alter it?

Comment: I *think* you'd just add them to /etc/hosts however I'm not putting this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

The cache is in the memory, not saved to the filesystem.
From `man dnsmasq`:

> ```
>    The  cache  statistics  are  also  available  in  the DNS as answers to
>    queries of class CHAOS and type TXT in domain bind.  The  domain  names
>    are   cachesize.bind,   insertions.bind,  evictions.bind,  misses.bind,
>    hits.bind, auth.bind and servers.bind.  An  example  command  to  query
>    this, using the dig utility would be
>
>    dig +short chaos txt cachesize.bind
> ```

Comment: Are you implying one cannot alter the cache in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can put those domain names in `/etc/hosts`. Don't forget to restart dnsmasq, since otherwise it won't reload it.

Dnsmasq reads and uses the data from `/etc/hosts`, which is one of the reasons I use it. I'm not sure whether it always does that, or it is configurable.

Comment: man dnsmasq, at least on my system, says " When it receives a SIGHUP, dnsmasq clears its cache and then re-loads /etc/hosts". And I've never seen dnsmasq pick up changes in /etc/hosts by itself. I simply restart it, SIGHUP would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the dnsmasq's cache content, but prefil it --

Create a `.conf` file under /etc/dnsmasq.d/, e.g., `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dbab.adblock.conf`, with the format of

```
address=/101com.com/192.168.2.101
address=/101order.com/192.168.2.101
...
```

For details refer to
https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2015/11/22/dbab-from-start-to-finish/

In the section "*Faq: How to blacklist those bad sites*".

Comment: What is the difference of prefilling to changing hosts?

Comment: prefil is the best answer to the question of _"I would like to alter my dnsmasq's cache so when I look for certain domains it'll give me the IP address I want it to serve"_